# What's it called when the band repeats the lyrics from the lead singer?

Tags: terminology

For example, in Level by The Raconteurs:

.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Call and response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_and_response_(music)) is the technique of trading off lyrical or musical lines in a piece. This [can take several forms](http://stevetres.com/2016/01/5-types-of-call-and-response-phrases/):

> - imitation
> - question and answer
> - statement and commentary
> - affirmation
> - surprise

Simply repeating the call in the response is [imitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imitation_(music)).

Comment: The middle link is worth following by the way, lots of good commentary and examples of call & response.

Comment: Awesome, that's what I was looking for.